# How can I add padding to the background image on a button programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-imagebutton

I'm creating a custom implementation that extends `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`. I am using `setBackground(Drawable)` in the button's constructor to put an image on the button, but want the image to be centered on the button with a little padding. How can I do this?

Comment: You need a exactly padding or some space will be good?

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged I don't have a particular value in mind but I want it to be consistent between all the buttons. Maybe like 5dp?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be using `ImageButton` instead of `Button`. If you do so, you can take whatever image you'd normally use and create an [Inset Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) from it, and then use that as the `src` attribute of your `ImageButton`.

Say you have a drawable `res/drawable-mdpi/mydrawable.png`. You could create `res/drawable/mydrawable_inset.xml` as follows:

```
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/mydrawable"
    android:insetTop="100dp"
    android:insetLeft="100dp"
    android:insetRight="100dp"
    android:insetBottom="100dp"/>
```

Here's a layout that includes one `ImageButton` with just `@drawable/mydrawable` and a second with `@drawable/mydrawable_inset`:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. But I do not have these ImageButton's defined in XML. They are created at runtime and the images are always different (pulled from the web at runtime). Can I do this programatically?

Comment: Sure, just use the `InsetDrawable` constructor that takes a `Drawable` and an `int` (inset in pixels): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html#InsetDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int)